# How to remap a key when it's pressed twice?

Tags: scripts, remapping, keys

Some of my keyboard keys has gone, so I’m trying to program the other keys that are still working to press the damaged keys when I press them twice. Is that possible? Is there any program that can help me in doing that?

I want to remap the key <kbd>J</kbd> to give 'm' when I press it twice.

**NB:** My laptop is a MacBook Pro 13" Unibody Mid 2012

Comment: In short, no. Maybe you can map a key combination to m.

Comment: What is your window manager? If you don't know, what is your distro?

Answer (score 6):

### Set aliases for characters, strings or complete lines

***UNLESS*** you are using wayland (Ubuntu 17.10, tested on Ubuntu Budgie 18.04, but Ubuntu Gnome 18.04 should be fine too), the snippet below will help you out.

#### How it works in practice

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> (or any other shortcut you set)
- A box appears

  [image]
- Type your "alias" (e.g. jj for m), the result shows (m), and the text will immediately be inserted at cursor position (or, if you prefer, after tapping <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>).

This script provides a single solution to set aliasses for a character, a string or even complete lines, just set the "alias" in the lines:

```py
replacements = [
    ["jj", "m"],
    ["aa", "q"],
    ["zz", "e"],
    ["mb", "monkey eats banana"],
]
```

In the latter case, typing "mb" will paste "monkey eats banana":

[image]

#### Setting up

1. You need to satisfy a few dependencies:

   - pyautogui:

     ```
     pip3 install pyautogui
     ```
   - pyperclip:

     ```
     sudo apt install python3-pyperclip xsel xclip
     ```
   - python3-xlib

     ```
     sudo apt install python3-xlib
     ```

   Log out and back in.
2. Copy the script below into an empty file, save it as `replace_keys.py`

   ```py
   #!/usr/bin/env python3
   import gi
   gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
   gi.require_version("Wnck", "3.0")
   from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, Wnck
   import subprocess
   import pyperclip
   import pyautogui
   import time


   """
   depends on
   - pyautogui:
     pip3 install pyautogui
   - pyperclip:
     sudo apt install python3-pyperclip xsel xclip
   """


   act_on_firstmatch = False


   replacements = [
       ["jj", "m"],
       ["aa", "q"],
       ["zz", "e"],
       ["mb", "monkey eats banana"],
   ]


   class KeyWin(Gtk.Window):

       def __init__(self):

           self.screendata = Wnck.Screen.get_default()
           self.screendata.force_update()
           self.curr_subject = self.screendata.get_active_window().get_xid()
           self.currmatch = ""
           Gtk.Window.__init__(self)
           maingrid = Gtk.Grid()
           self.add(maingrid)
           self.set_decorated(False)
           self.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER)
           self.connect("key-release-event", self.check_key)
           self.keyentry = Gtk.Entry()
           self.keyentry.connect("changed", self.update_current)
           self.label = Gtk.Label("")
           self.label.set_width_chars(10)
           maingrid.attach(self.keyentry, 0, 0, 1, 1)
           maingrid.attach(self.label, 1, 0, 1, 1)
           self.show_all()
           self.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
           Gtk.main()

       def update_current(self, widget):
           curr = self.keyentry.get_text()
           self.currmatch = ""
           for s in replacements:
               if curr == s[0]:
                   self.currmatch = s[1]
                   if act_on_firstmatch:
                       self.replace()
           self.label.set_width_chars(len(self.currmatch) + 4)
           self.label.set_text(self.currmatch)


       def replace(self, *args):
           pyperclip.copy(self.currmatch)

           subprocess.call(["wmctrl", "-ia", str(self.curr_subject)])
           Gtk.main_quit()

       def check_key(self, button, val):
           typed = Gdk.keyval_name(val.keyval)
           if typed == "Control_L":
               self.replace()

   KeyWin()
   time.sleep(0.05)
   pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v')
   ```
3. Set up your aliasses (KEEP THE INDENTATION!) in the section:

   ```py
   replacements = [
       ["jj", "m"],
       ["aa", "q"],
       ["zz", "e"],
       ["mb", "monkey eats banana"],
   ]
   ```
4. If you want, change

   ```
   act_on_firstmatch = False
   ```

   into

   ```
   act_on_firstmatch = True
   ```

   if you like to insert immediately without tapping <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>
5. Set up a shortcut key **with** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> **as modifier**. I used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> in my test to run the script by the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/replace_keys.py
   ```

And you're done!

Comment: Does this script understand to map `jj` to `m` and `JJ` to `M`?

Comment: @αғsнιη string comparison is case sensitive, so yes, it does.

Comment: Of course, for any solution like this (including my answer), you need a working keyboard to write the code. It would also be possible to specify the missing keys using their numeric values with escape sequences in whatever coding language is used - assuming those keys work.

Answer (score 0):

I have two machines that have this problem of worn out/broken keys. I have found two solutions:

1. Spend ten bucks for a WiFi USB keyboard (Logitech has a good one). Generally the BIOS will see it and grab it before the OS.
2. Load a remote control piece of software (RealVNC is free for small setups and will cross different OSs)

Both work depending on the access needed.

Comment: What does the remote control software do?

Comment: Realvnc just controls the keyboard, mouse and screen remotely so I can do simple maintenance from my desk through the network. I don't have to worry about a broken keyboard, mouse or monitor since I'm using the one at my desk. Linux has a version of this but I need to go from one OS to others and this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Although @jacobvlijm 's answer is more specific, another alternative is to use a program like [AutoKey](https://github.com/autokey/autokey) . It does many things to automate your desktop by generating keyboard and mouse input from trigger phrases and hotkey presses.

In particular, you can define a phrase for each of the broken keys and have it triggered by a trigger phrase that is any combination of working keypresses not likely to occur in your actual typing. These phrases can be set to trigger immediately from within a word.

There's also an option that puts the trigger text you just typed back in if you immediately press the backspace key if you ever need the trigger characters as is.

All of this can be configured using the AutoKey GUI interface with no actual coding required.

For more complex requirements, AutoKey can run full Python scripts triggered by phrases or hotkeys which are only limited by the user's imagination and knowledge of Python.