# Is there any application or command that lets you insert special characters, umlauts and foreign letters

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, keyboard-layout, language-support

I write and work in several languages: German, Spanish, French, Greek, English. In mac when you press a key longer than 2 seconds you can choose between special characters derivative from a main character. In windows there is a software called Holdkey that does the same. Is there anything similar in Linux. I haven't found it yet.

Comment: Did you see this site: https://www.maketecheasier.com/quickly-type-special-characters-linux/

Comment: The [on-screen keyboard](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-osk.html) includes that feature.

Comment: Thank you @GunnarHjalmarsson. However I forgot to mention I use Kubuntu... KDE does not include this option.

Comment: KDE has a tutorial on the topic of configuring the compose key https://userbase.kde.org/Tutorials/ComposeKey

Comment: Note: typing `^e` gives `ê`

Answer (score 2):

I have two advices:

1. Use a suitable keyboard layout, i.e. a layout with dead keys. If you have an English keyboard, pick for instance *English (US, intl., with dead keys)*. But there are several other variants.
2. Define a [compose key](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/tips-specialchars.html#compose). That way you'll be able to type many characters which are not included in the keyboard layout you are using. (Compose key is a XKB feature, so it's available on Kubuntu, but you need to figure out how to define it there.)

Comment: Thank you! I didn't thought about the use of English (US, intl., with dead keys). This idea is very use to configure and very easy to use. I choosed EurKEY (US based layout with european letters) for my use is perfect.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not afraid to set up (instructions should be clear), below could give you an alternative to quickly insert your often used special character (-alternatives).

#### Editable special character tool

The script below is a flexible tool (window to insert characters from, in a click) to have often used characters available in a second:

[image]

#### How it works

- Call the window with a shortcut
- To insert a character, simply click on it, and it will paste the character into the window you were working in.
- To add a set of characters, press <kbd>+</kbd>
  A text editor window will open, add your "family" name on the first line, related special characters on the next lines, one character per line, for example:

  ```
  a
  å
  ä
  ã
  â
  á
  à
  ª
  ```

  (from the image). Close the file, the special characters will be available from now on from the next time you call the window.
- to delete a set of available characters, press <kbd>x</kbd>

#### How to set up

1. You need to satisfy a few dependencies:

   - python3-xlib

     ```
     sudo apt install python3-xlib
     ```
   - pyautogui:

     ```
     pip3 install pyautogui
     ```
   - pyperclip:

     ```
     sudo apt install python3-pyperclip xsel xclip
     ```
   - You might have to install Wnck:

     ```
     python3-gi gir1.2-wnck-3.0
     ```

   Log out and back in.
2. Copy the script below into an empty file, save it as `specialchars.py` and ***make it executable***

   ```py
   #!/usr/bin/env python3
   import os
   import gi
   gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
   gi.require_version('Wnck', '3.0')
   from gi.repository import Gtk, Wnck, Gdk
   import subprocess
   import pyperclip
   import pyautogui


   css_data = """
   .label {
     font-weight: bold;
     color: blue;
   }
   .delete {
     color: red;
   }
   """

   fpath = os.environ["HOME"] + "/.specialchars"

   def create_dirs():
       try:
           os.mkdir(fpath)
       except FileExistsError:
           pass


   def listfiles():
       files = os.listdir(fpath)
       chardata = []
       for f in files:
           f = os.path.join(fpath, f)
           chars = [s.strip() for s in open(f).readlines()]
           try:
               category = chars[0]
               members = chars[1:]
           except IndexError:
               os.remove(f)
           else:
               chardata.append([category, members, f])
       chardata.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
       return chardata


   def create_newfamily(button):
       print("yay")
       n = 1
       while True:
           name = "charfamily_" + str(n)
           file = os.path.join(fpath, name)
           if os.path.exists(file):
               n = n + 1
           else:
               break
       open(file, "wt").write("")
       subprocess.Popen(["xdg-open", file])


   class Window(Gtk.Window):
       def __init__(self):
           Gtk.Window.__init__(self)
           self.set_decorated(False)
           # self.set_active(True)
           self.set_keep_above(True);
           self.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER_ALWAYS)
           self.connect("key-press-event", self.get_key)
           self.set_default_size(0, 0)
           self.provider = Gtk.CssProvider.new()
           self.provider.load_from_data(css_data.encode())
           self.maingrid = Gtk.Grid()
           self.add(self.maingrid)
           chardata = listfiles()
           # get the currently active window
           self.screendata = Wnck.Screen.get_default()
           self.screendata.force_update()
           self.curr_subject = self.screendata.get_active_window().get_xid()
           row = 0
           for d in chardata:
               bbox = Gtk.HBox()
               fambutton = Gtk.Button(d[0])
               fambutton_cont = fambutton.get_style_context()
               fambutton_cont.add_class("label")
               fambutton.connect("pressed", self.open_file, d[2])
               Gtk.StyleContext.add_provider(
                   fambutton_cont,
                   self.provider,
                   Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION,
               )
               fambutton.set_tooltip_text(
                   "Edit special characters of '" + d[0] + "'"
               )
               bbox.pack_start(fambutton, False, False, 0)
               for c in d[1]:
                   button = Gtk.Button(c)
                   button.connect("pressed", self.replace, c)
                   button.set_size_request(1, 1)
                   bbox.pack_start(button, False, False, 0)
               self.maingrid.attach(bbox, 0, row, 1, 1)
               deletebutton = Gtk.Button("X")

               deletebutton_cont = deletebutton.get_style_context()
               deletebutton_cont.add_class("delete")
               Gtk.StyleContext.add_provider(
                   deletebutton_cont,
                   self.provider,
                   Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION,
               )

               deletebutton.connect("pressed", self.delete_file, d[2], bbox)
               deletebutton.set_tooltip_text("Delete family")

               self.maingrid.attach(deletebutton, 100, row, 1, 1)
               row = row + 1
           addbutton = Gtk.Button("+")
           addbutton.connect("pressed", create_newfamily)
           addbutton.set_tooltip_text("Add family")
           self.maingrid.attach(addbutton, 100, 100, 1, 1)
           self.maingrid.attach(Gtk.Label("- Press Esc to exit -"), 0, 100, 1, 1)
           self.show_all()
           Gtk.main()

       def get_key(self, button, val):
           # keybinding to close the previews
           if Gdk.keyval_name(val.keyval) == "Escape":
               Gtk.main_quit()

       def replace(self, button, char, *args):
           pyperclip.copy(char)
           subprocess.call(["wmctrl", "-ia", str(self.curr_subject)])
           pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v')
           Gtk.main_quit()


       def open_file(self, button, path):
           subprocess.Popen(["xdg-open", path])

       def delete_file(self, button, path, widget):
           os.remove(path)
           widget.destroy()
           button.destroy()
           self.resize(10, 10)

   create_dirs()
   Window()
   ```
3. Set up a shortcut key to run:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/specialchars.py
   ```

On first run, you will only see a <kbd>+</kbd> button. Start Adding your character "families" and restart (-call) the window to have all available in a click.

That's it...

Comment: Interesting solution, hence +1'ed but just one question: why `python3-xlib` is necessary ? I don't see Xlib being imported anywhere in the code

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Aarrgh, copied too much over from my answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071218/how-to-remap-a-key-when-its-pressed-twice/1071454#1071454 thanks for mentioning!

Comment: Haha, either script  or copy and paste all the things - that's the way to go XD  I'll look over the other answer as well. Thanks for the weekend read.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Hah, I *only* copied the install instructions! :)

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy waitwai!! Autogui uses Xlib...

Comment: That makes sense. I'm surprised it's not an automatic dependency with `pip3` installation, because xlib is available via pip as well

Comment: This is a neat solution, I was just looking for something that is like an android keyboard since I do not type special symbols so often so remembering tons of compose key combos is a too big overhead. Any chance this or an alternative comes as a packaged program?

Comment: @oglop It actually is, but much improved, now running from a daemon & integrated in Ubuntu Budgie. https://github.com/ubuntubudgie/quickchar/tree/1fe82efe19b64aa428bed4a8d56991c7ff46150a

Answer (score 0):

You can use unicode to type special characters on Linux.

To type a special character, first press down <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> and then let go of the keys.

Next, type the hexadecimal code for the character you wish to insert and then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

The hexadecimal code for "ü" is `00fc`.

[Click here to see the Wikipedia page for Unicode characters.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters)

[Click here to see the Wikipedia page for Unicode math characters.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_operators_and_symbols_in_Unicode)

Comment: Clarification: Hold CTRL and SHIFT hit U, let go of CTRL and SHIFT keys, type the code, press enter.

Comment: Thanks for this idea. However for me personally I think the best option is to use a Keyboard layout. I found EurKEY (US based layout with european letters) the best for people who need German language characters as well as Spanish. I will use you idea for greek characters that I don't use that often.

Comment: @Hannu You can let go of all the keys CTRL and SHIFT and U. There is no need to hold down U while you type the code.

Comment: "hit U" = no holding.

Comment: @Hannu Although, you *can* hold down U when you type the code you just don't *need* to. Either way works.